# How to iterate over json object in square brackets

Tags: angular, ngfor

How to iterate Json object in square brackets?

[image: Json role object]

This is the Json object "roles"

```
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "Admin" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Editor" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Viewer"}
]
```

This is not working:

```
<tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <td>{{role.id}}</td>
    <td>{{role.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on what is not working, what error did you get?

Comment: I just try to iterate the object as mentioned. There is no error.

Comment: are you assigning that value to `this.roles`?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes.
`this.roleservice.all().subscribe(roles => this.roles = roles);`

Comment: Do the elements show up when you inspect the dom?  Are you using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Comment: @BizzyBob there is no need to use ChangeDetection because the object is accessible as you can see in the console.

Comment: I was just trying to troubleshoot. If OnPush is enabled, it may prevent dom from updating.

Comment: Do items show up if you hardcode the value in the component? `public roles = [{"id":1,"name":"Admin"}, ...];` ?

Comment: @BizzyBob how to hardcode that?

Comment: `{{ roles | json }}` showing anything? to rule out any css issues

Comment: @NaveenJ nothing

Comment: I try this: `<tr *ngFor="let role of [0].roles">` but shows nothing also